# take user back to previous activity after taking photo using android camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-activity

I am working on camera related app in android. What I want is when user takes photo he should be immediately take to previous activity where he was before. Right now what my code does is when user takes a photo then two button appear at the bottom of the screen i.e. Save and Discard. So I do not want that. When the picture is taken user should be directly navigate to previous activity. How can acheive this?

Here is my code

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView iv;
Button bCapture, bSetWall;
Intent i;
int CameraResult = 0;
Bitmap bmp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}

private void initialize() {
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
    bCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCapture);
    bSetWall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSetWall);
    bCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
    bSetWall.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bCapture:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
        break;
    case R.id.bSetWall:
        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: By looking at your requirement i would suggest to implement your own camera code using SurfaceHolder.here is good tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

Answer (score 0):

The code you have right now will capture photos using an existing camera application. That is, it is making use of an already existing Activity that belongs to some camera application that is installed on your device.

That said, there is no way to manipulate `Activity`s that belong to other applications. You'll have to implement your own [Camera Activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html) instead.